# Uploading *.dwg layers to QGIS

Tags: dwg

I have many `*.dwg` layers I want to upload.

How do I upload them without losing information?

I usually convert them to `*.dxf` but I realised it merged everything into one layer.

Comment: Have you checked the attribute table to see if the layers are in there as attributes?

Comment: You can use the plugin "[Another DXF Importer / DX][1]F2Shape Converter". 


  [1]: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AnotherDXF2Shape/

Comment: Do you have AutoCAD in your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Project -> Import/Export -> Import layers from DWG/DXF" and voila. Not sure if you can do it programmatically in this way but it works for a DWG file.

Comment: My qgis doesnt even find dwg files

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: @AvigailNewman-Cohen I have found that DWG import can be painfully slow. I would recommend converting them to dxf first. You shouldn’t loose your layers if you use Grey’s process.